# What happens after resuming from a tombstoned state?

Tags: windows-phone-8

When the user resumes an app that was tombstoned, does it start on the main app page and you have to handle with saved states to check where was the user and send him there again, or does it open directly the page where the user was and all you have to do is to restore your variables and date from the saved state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tombstoned**

*A tombstoned app has been terminated, **but the operating system preserves information about its navigation state and also preserves the state dictionaries the app populated during Deactivated.** The device will maintain tombstoning information for up to five apps at a time. If an app is tombstoned and the user navigates back to the application, it will be relaunched and the application can use the preserved data to restore state.*

More info in [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

So, the navigation is kept, but you need to restore the state. You can always test this - in project properties, go to debug and select

*Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging*

So when you deactivate the app while debugging, it will actually go to tombstoned state and you can test it properly.